# test Image onError call in react native

Tags: image, react-native, jestjs

I have a component that wraps Image component and calls an internal function when Image's on error gets called

```
  render() {
const {
  avatars, userId, size, containerStyle, onPress, currentUserId,
} = this.props
const { hasError } = this.state
this.onError = this.onError.bind(this)
const id = userId || currentUserId
return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
    <Image
      source={avatars && avatars[id] && !hasError
        ? { uri: avatars[id].localPath } : defaultAvatar}
      style={{
        width: size, height: size, borderRadius: size / 2, ...containerStyle,
      }}
      onError={this.onError}
    />
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
 )
}
}
```

Now I want to test my components this.onError function works correctly, is there a way to mock react-native image component and force it to run the onError function so I can test my fuction using jest?

Comment: It's a good practice to ensure that the work being done by `this.onError` is done, so when the implementation is changed that work is still being done. So if you post your `onError` method you might receive some better answers

Answer (score 2):

In short, this is how you want to trigger onError function in your test

```
fireEvent(getByTestId("img"), "error");
```

You can of course choose to use any other getter instead of getByTestId if you want, but I prefer to have testId's in most cases.

Below I have explained it with a more detailed example.
If my component is this :

```
const DisplayAnImage = () => {
 return (
  <Image
    testID="imgTest"
    style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
    source={{
      uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
    }}
  />
 );
}

export default DisplayAnImage;
```

Then I would trigger onError function like this in my test :

```
 test("test to trigger on error function", async () => {
   const { getByTestId } = render(<DisplayAnImage />);
   fireEvent(getByTestId("imgTest"), "error");
   // write your assertions here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a invalid `uri` in `source` prop.

e.g

Just replace

```
uri: avatars[id].localPath
```

with

```
uri: avatars[id].localPath + ".random"
```

Comment: this didnt work possibly because im using a shallow rended, sorry if that was important information i left out

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution was just to simulate the error callback like this

```
 wrapper.find('Image').simulate('error')
    expect(wrapper.state('hasError')).toEqual(true)
```